# Zinc organic-water solvent extraction (Hydrometallurgy)

Tags: equilibrium, solvents, extraction

Consider a biphasical system consisting of an aqueous phase and an organic phase.
Consider the following equation:

> $\ce{Zn^2+(aq) + 2HR(org) <=> ZnR2(org) + 2H+(aq)}$

- Let [ $Zn^{+2}$ ]$^{0}$$(aq)$ = 0,1 $\pu{mol L-1}$ be the initial concentration of ionic zinc in the aqueous phase.
- Let $\ce{[HR]}$$^{0}$$(org)$ = 0,5 $\pu{mol L-1}$ be the initial concentration of phosphinic acid in the organic phase.
- Consider that the volume of the organic phase $\ce{V2}$ is twice the volume of the aqueous phase $\ce{V1}$ ($\ce{V2} = \ce{2V1}$ )
- Consider that the equilibrium constant of the equation above is $K = 10^{-3,259}$
- Let $D = \frac{[Zn^{+2}]}{\ce{[ZnR2]}}$ be the distribution coefficient of the equilibrium above and $E = \frac{100D\ce{V2}}{D\ce{V2}+\ce{V1}}$ be the extraction coeficcient. (note that since $\ce{V2} = \ce{2V1}$ , $E = \frac{100D}{D+0.5}$ )

Given the information above,plot the graphic of E versus the ph of the aqueous phase.
*Suggestion*: Use $\ce{V1} = 1L$ and $\ce{V2} = 2L$

---

My attempt at it:
Assuming $\ce{V1} = 1L$ $\ce{V2} = 2L$ and assuming that $\ce{n0,n1}$ are the initial mols of ionic zinc and phosphinic acid respectively,we obtain that $\ce{n0} = 0.1 mol$ and $\ce{n1} = 1 mol$.Also assume that $x$ is the quantity (in mols) of $\ce{Zn^2+(aq)}$ that reacted.Noting that we are analysing the equilibrium for each $\ce{[H+]}$ ,after we draw the reaction table we obtain:
$K = \frac{2x\ce{[H+]^{2}}}{(0.1-x)(1-2x)^{2}}$ and $D =\frac{0.5x}{0.1-x}$ .If we consider $2x <<<< 1$ we obtain that $K \approx \frac{2x\ce{[H+]^{2}}}{(0.1-x)(1)^{2}}$ $=>$ $K \approx 4D\ce{[H+]^{2}}$ and with that we obtain a relation between D and the ph of the aqueous phase.After that I was able to plot the graphic of E versus the ph.
Did I answer it correctly?Any help/correction would be kindly appreciated.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ph is probably pH. See also [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) 
(element and unit symbol upright)  and `$n = \pu{1 mol}$` as $n = \pu{1 mol}$ // See CH SE META post about [policy for "Am I right?" questions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/policy-on-amirite-questions)